# Is it possible to represent a formula in SVG?

Tags: svg, graphing

Is it possible to represent a formula in SVG? For example, `y = x^2` should be graphed as a parabola.

I created something like that using a graphical tool, but when I saved to SVG and examined the file, it appeared to have created a `<path>` with many, many points, which sort of defeats the idea of using vectors; it's more like encoding the pixels required.

Answer (score 1):

No, SVG does not natively support creating paths with an arbitrary formula. It only supports cubic and quadratic Bézier curves, and elliptical arcs.

The quadratic Bézier curve does allow drawing of parabolic segments, but it's typical that a graphing calculator type of program would not take advantage of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute a quadratic (not cubic) Bézier curve control points from a quadratic curve quite simply.

- The first point is where your curve starts
- The second point is "in the middle", so that tangents to both sides align
- The third point is where your curve stops.

This [interactive quadratic SVG visualization](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/svg-curves/quadratic-curve.html) is quite instrumental.